# If statements for a Secure Password Game

Tags: python-3.x

For my homeowork assignment I need to create a Secure Password game where the user will be able to input there own password and the program will run to see if the password is qualified as a sucure Password.
If not then it will print out the reasons why it's not, and let you input a different password.

I just need help on the If statement for the "if countsymbols" below.

The password needs to contain atleast 1 of the 6 special symbols listed.

I'm new to python, so any help will be great!

So far this is what I have.

---

```
print ("Welcome to the PASSWORD game of \"Jojo\"!")

Password = input( "Please enter a password (Enter q to quit): ")

#When the user inputs "q" then the Game will end.
q = quit
if Password == q:
    quit
print("Thank you for playing this PASSWORD game. Hope to see you again! ")

# Start of code.

while (Password != q):
    print("The password you just entered is", Password)

countsymbols = 6  # of 6 special symbols $ % @ ! ? *

countsymbols += pw.count('$')+pw.count('%')+pw.count('@') +pw.count('!') +pw.count('?') 

if countsymbols  #I NEED HELP HERE

print( "Your password is not secure since it contains none of 6 special symbols: $ % @ ! ? *")
```

Comment: What do you want to happen in the if-statement? Please explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: I want it to check that the 'INPUT' has atleast 1 of the 6 special characters listed($ % @ ! ? *). If not then I want the loop to stop and for it to print "Your password is not secure since it contains none of 6 special symbols: $ % @ ! ? *". Right now I'm trying If countsymbols.find(password)